# Android https request fails weirdly

Tags: java, android, http, kotlin, https

I try to make an https request using following code

```
(object : Thread(){
            override fun run() {
                super.run()
                val url = URL("https://europe-west3-ronda-32e4a.cloudfunctions.net/myFunction")
                val urlConnection: URLConnection = url.openConnection()
                val inpS: InputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream()
            }
        }).start()
```

but sometimes it fails and sometimes it works, I don't know what's happening please help me

error log :

```
java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to europe-west3-ronda-32e4a.cloudfunctions.net/2001:4860:4802:36::36:443
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:1409)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:1359)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:221)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:144)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:106)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:400)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:333)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:483)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:429)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:252)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:211)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
        at com.sandukhan.ronda.Server$sendMove$1.run(Server.kt:431)
```

Comment: Hi, is there any reason why you are sticking with the native android's okHttp library and not using Retrofit or OkHttp instead?

Comment: no there is no reason it was just the first result I found on google I will see your suggestions. thank you

Comment: I used OkHttp it works fine thanks

Comment: Nice. I have posted an answer for the comment which you can accept, so that it is visible to others. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is there any reason why you are sticking with the native android's okHttp library and not using Retrofit or OkHttp instead?

Android development usually use OkHttp for doing HTTP requests. I would prefer to use that instead.